# rails iframe tag not extracted from text

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, iframe, sanitize

I've been struggling to embed iframe tag into a page with Ruby on Rails. Here's what I do:

1. Admin inputs text that has  tag in it in textarea
2. saves to the database with save button
3. user retrieves the text
4. displays text

Input is as below:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaa
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://
www.youtube.com/embed/Z4jib_xBTtY" frameborder="0"></iframe>
bbbbbbbbbbbbb
```

and it displayed like this:
[image: the output of the text]

For 2 and 3, I've confirmed that the  tag is actually saved and retrieved in text data.

Since  tag is there displayed as a functioning  tag in view, I assume it's not possible to embed tags this way and it must have to do with security issue.

I've tried (with haml):

- = simple_format(@product.description),
- = simple_format(@product.description, {}, sanitize: false),
- = sanitize(@product.description),
- = raw(@product.description)

, but so far I've had no luck. (All with the same output put above)

Comment: Where do you want to put text to? Did you try to use ```<%= your_text %?```  inside the html tag.

Answer (score 1):

This will fix your problem:

```
<%= sanitize @product.description, tags: %w( iframe ), attributes: %w(src source width height %>
```

This calls the sanitize method on @product.description, and allows the tag iframe and the attributes src, source, width and height to be rendered in the page, not escaped.

Rails escaps HTML fed from the database by default, for security reasons. You'll want to read up on cross sight scripting soon, and the sanitize gem (used above), but for your purposes you can start with this [this](http://blog.arkency.com/2015/09/sanitizing-html-input-youtube-iframes/)

Your markup will be a bit different, since you are using haml.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me with Rails 7 in in Jan. 2023. Note - your code snippet is missing a parenthesis on the end ) .